# Fix the location of a UIButton when zoom in or zoom out image Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, imageview, zooming

**Original Screen Shot:**

[image: Original Screen Shot]

I need to show an image, and above it some buttons that correspond to certain clickable areas of the image, the problem is that the image has zoom, and when i zoom the image, the buttons do not stay in the same place as the picture given below:

[image: Problem Screen Shot]

My problem is that the button does not appears in the right place like show in original image.

**MainStoryBoard Constraints Screen Shot:**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your views like in below hierarchy;

```
-> UIView
 ->ScrollView
   ->UIImageView
 ->UIButton
 ->UIButton
 ->UIButton
```

So Z position of `UIScrollView` should be 0 and `UIButtons` should be on top of It.

You can get more Info about how to zoom UIImageview with UIScrollView from 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/560-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started

In addition: UIScrollView and UIButtons constraints should not be related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding constraints of buttons with respect to the parent View ,or you cant make an object for constraint, for Example, **@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!** where heightConstraint is the object which you drag from a particular constraint so when the zoom is done you can make the constraints constant by using property heightConstraint.constant = x